# How to reuse a CodeIgniter Active Record Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to...

1. Set some query parameters and filters.
2. Get the total number of matching rows.
3. Set limit and offset.
4. Get the results

Here's what I initially tried:

```
$this->db->select(<aggregation, subqueries>);
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where(<complex filters>);

$total = $this->db->count_all_results();

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

But calling `count_all_results` calls `_reset_select` internally meaning I have to do the first step again - not very DRY.

How would you achieve this in a simple, clean way?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve all of these results at once in the same call?

Comment: No, I only want a limited set (the first 10 for example) but I also want to get the total count of rows that match my query.

Answer (score 1):

*Just use Query Builder Caching*

```
$this->db->start_cache();

$this->db->select(<aggregation, subqueries>);
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where(<complex filters>);

$this->db->stop_cache();

$total = $this->db->count_all_results();

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

$query = $this->db->get();
$this->db->flush_cache();

$result = $query->result();
```

> https://codeigniter-30-dev.readthedocs.io/zh_TW/latest/database/query_builder.html#this-db-count-all-results